# Возможно ли получить всю строку из сформированой подзапросом таблицы по максимальному значению столбца?

Tags: mysql

Задание описано в первой строчке кода

```
SELECT  тут нужно получить всю строку(тоесть m.disp_id и moves_count_for_disp) где MAX(moves_count_for_disp)(тоесть где значения этого поля больше чем другие)
FROM    (
        SELECT      m.disp_id, COUNT(m.disp_id) moves_count_for_disp
        FROM        car_move m
                    INNER JOIN car_disp d ON d.disp_id = m.disp_id
        WHERE       MONTH(date_exec) = 1
        GROUP BY    m.disp_id
        ) disp_moves_count
```

Вот таблица которая получается в результате подзапроса(disp_moves_count):
[image: Вот таблица которая получается в результате подзапроса(disp_moves_count)]

Вроде бы попытался описать доступно что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно так:

```
SELECT m.disp_id, COUNT(m.disp_id) moves_count
FROM car_move m
INNER JOIN car_disp d ON d.disp_id = m.disp_id
WHERE MONTH(date_exec) = 1
GROUP BY m.disp_id
HAVING moves_count = (
SELECT MAX(moves_count_for_disp)
FROM (
        SELECT      m.disp_id, COUNT(m.disp_id) moves_count_for_disp
        FROM        car_move m
                    INNER JOIN car_disp d ON d.disp_id = m.disp_id
        WHERE       MONTH(date_exec) = 1
        GROUP BY    m.disp_id
        ) disp_moves_count
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для выбора одной строки с максимальным значением поля можно отсортировать вашу таблицу в порядке убывания значений вашего поля и взять первую строчку:

```
SELECT
FROM    (
        SELECT      m.disp_id, COUNT(m.disp_id) moves_count_for_disp
        FROM        car_move m
                    INNER JOIN car_disp d ON d.disp_id = m.disp_id
        WHERE       MONTH(date_exec) = 1
        GROUP BY    m.disp_id
        ) disp_moves_count
ORDER BY moves_count_for_disp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: нужна возможность выбирать неизвестное количество строк

Comment: максимальное значение ведь одно да? :-) И в вопросе вы пишите "получить всю строку"